# Where did the MacPro 6,1 "Computer Sleep" setting go?

Tags: sleep-wake, mac-pro, energy

Anybody got a clue where the MacPro6,1 power / sleep setting went?

The only thing I can set is the "Turn display off after" slider.

On my old MacPro2,1 there were two settings:

- Computer sleep
- Display sleep

**New MacPro6,1 Energy Saver Dialog**:

[image: MacPro6,1 energy settings]

**MacPro2,1 / MacPro4,1 Energy Saver Dialog**:

[image]

edit 1:

More frustrating, my PC goes into **sleep/standby** even when im running something like Terminal with SSH session.  On the old system you could set a different sleep for the computer (i'm fine my screen goes to sleep in 5 minutes).

```
$ pmset -g 

Active Profiles:
AC Power        -1*
Currently in use:
 standby              1
 Sleep On Power Button 1
 womp                 1
 autorestart          0
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 darkwakes            0
 gpuswitch            2
 networkoversleep     0
 disksleep            10
 sleep                1
 autopoweroffdelay    14400
 hibernatemode        0
 autopoweroff         1
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         10
 standbydelay         10800
```

Comment: what happens when you use restore defaults? and what os is it?

Comment: nothing, my mac is just a few days old. I guess since it doesn't have a HDD (but SSD) Apple thinks we don't need it?

Comment: That is funny :) you should be able to set it, and not have Apple boss you around. run the pmset -g in terminal to see your current settings.

Answer (score 1):

It is probable that Apple no longer feels the **Computer sleep** and **Display sleep** options are required.

The new Mac Pro has no spinning hard disk drives and has a modern power management system that can manage itself.

I suspect you can change settings using low level tools like [pmset](http://www.dssw.co.uk/reference/pmset.html), but that those settings will be ignored.

### Staying Awake

To keep your Mac awake during long running processes, use the **Terminal.app** command [caffeinate](http://www.dssw.co.uk/reference/caffeinate.html):

```
caffeinate
```

Comment: Thanks, right (makes sense). Any idea how i can keep it awake while my screen can goto sleep (like with a huge download) ?

Comment: @Rogier terminal ping -i 300 google.com keeps the network alive till you kill it.

Comment: To keep your Mac awake during a long download, use the http://www.dssw.co.uk/reference/caffeinate.html command e.g. `caffeinate`. Ideally, your downloading application will register a 'do not sleep assertion' and this will avoid idle time sleep interrupting your download.

Comment: even when i use ping from terminal it goes to sleep :(

Comment: @GrahamMiln,  thank you for pointing out caffeinated. I wrapped caffeinated inside my *bash_profile*, so when starting a ssh session it automatically "caffeinates" ssh.